# spark job gets stuck when running in multiple executors

Tags: apache-spark

Issue: spark program get stuck or hangs when running under local[k] mode, where k is set to 8.

Error Message:

```
 2015-05-20 00:55:19 INFO  Executor:59 - Finished task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID      10). 2471 bytes result sent to driver
 2015-05-20 00:55:19 INFO  TaskSetManager:59 - Finished task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10) in 2658752 ms on localhost (13/15)
 TaskSetManager:59 - Finished task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10) in 2658752 ms on localhost (13/15)
 TaskSetManager:59 - Finished task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10) in 2658752 ms on localhost (13/15))
```

Situation: 
Spark version: 1.3.0
This issue occurs when I run spark in multiple executors say 8. When it's less than 3, there is no such error.

Anyone encounters the same problem or have some solution in mind?

Comment: Could be anything  Can you post a short example that reliably fails?

Comment: It's just a simple Spark program,  just performing some map functions that process text line to some required format.

Comment: Hey, I am facing same issue. Any leads on this?

Comment: @COSTA, see my reply in the Answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't have any clue in solving the issue directly. However, the error is gone when I set smaller number for threads, say k=2 or 4.